# using with class & namespace differencies/ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm just curious why it is designed in that way with using directive. For 1) struct is treated like namespace and for 2) it is not:

```
struct foo
{
  using type0 = int;
};

namespace bar
{
  using type1 = int;
}

using bar::type1; 
using type0 = foo::type0; // 1)
using foo::type0;         // 2)
```

---

```
clang version 3.3 (branches/release_33 186829)
clang -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp:13:12: error: using declaration can not refer to class member
using foo::type0;
```

### ~~~~~^

```
gcc version 4.8.1
c++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp:13:12: error: ‘foo’ is not a namespace
using foo::type0;
```

Comment: *1)* is a typedef, *2)* is a using declaration. They're not the same thing.

Comment: But typedef in 1) treats foo like a namespace to declare type0 form type0 in namespace foo. all types inside foo struct are in foo namespace ,not in global namespace.

Comment: 1) is a type alias - its like a typedef...

Answer (score 11):

Classes are not namespaces; they have a strict scope. The name of a class member (when accessed outside of the class) must *always* be prefixed by the class name.

`using` isn't allowed to change that.

The reason #1 works is because you creating a *type alias* to the type declared in the class. That's what `using name = typename;` does. In this case, it's no different from a `typedef`.

#2 doesn't create an alias; that syntax expects to be given a name within a namespace to bring into the current namespace.